# Getting Unsupported or non-existing property name Exception in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

I am trying to add `sys_category` in my own custom modal by using this code in my `setup.txt`

```
config.tx_extbase {
    objects {
        TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\Category {
            className = ABC\MyExt\Domain\Model\Category
        }
    TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Repository\CategoryRepository {
        className = ABC\MyExt\Domain\Repository\CategoryRepository
        }
    }
}

plugin.tx_myext {
    persistence {
        classes {
            ABC\MyExt\Domain\Model\Category {
                mapping {
                    tableName = sys_category
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but I am getting this exception `Unsupported or non-existing property name \"categories\" used in relation matching`

and in my model I am using this

```
/**
 * categories
 *
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\ABC\MyExt\Domain\Model\Category>
 */
protected $categories = null;
```

what am I doing wrong in making the relation?

My TCA I am using this in the `ext_tables.php`

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::makeCategorizable(
            'myext',
            'tx_myext_domain_model_tablename,
            // Do not use the default field name ("categories") for pages, tt_content, sys_file_metadata, which is already used
            'categories',
            array(
                // Set a custom label
                'label'              => 'LLL:EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:additional_categories',
                // This field should not be an exclude-field
                'exclude'            => false,
                // Override generic configuration, e.g. sort by title rather than by sorting
                'fieldConfiguration' => array(
                    'foreign_table_where' => ' AND sys_category.sys_language_uid IN (-1, 0) ORDER BY sys_category.title ASC',
                ),
                // string (keyword), see TCA reference for details
                'l10n_mode'          => 'exclude',
                // list of keywords, see TCA reference for details
                'l10n_display'       => 'hideDiff',
            )
        );
```

and in the table I have this `categories int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,`

Comment: Did you clear the cache in the installtool?

Comment: yes did that just now but still having the exception

Comment: Can you post your controller and repository?

Comment: @ThomasLöffler `class CategoryRepository extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Repository\CategoryRepository {

 protected $defaultOrderings = array( 'title' => \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING );
// other methods here
}`

and my model is just blank `class Category extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\Category
{
}
`

Answer (score 0):

Frontend requests do not load `ext_tables.php` in requests anymore since TYPO3 8.5 ([TYPO3 CMS Core ChangeLog](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/8.5/Breaking-78384-FrontendIgnoresTCAInExtTables.html)).

The call of `makeCategorizable()` has to be moved to `Configuration/TCA/Overrides/<table>.php`.